# Laravel 8 vue get request returns nothing

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am using Laravel 8 with Vue.js and axios. I am trying to display a bunch of menu items in a list. The request works in postman, and if I manually enter the json into vue tools, I get my list. But I can't seem to get the data to pull through with my vue method. I am hoping someone might see where I went wrong. Thanks.

My controller,

```
public function index(Request $request, Item $item)
    {
        $items = Item::all();

        return response()->json($items, 200);
    }
```

The Route

```
Route::get('/item', [MenuItemController::class, 'index']);
```

and the the vue script

```
<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                items: []
            }
        },

        methods: {
            getMenuItem () {
                var that = this;
                axios.get('http://buffet.test:8000/item').then((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                    that.items = response.data;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.errored = true
                });
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            this.getMenuItem
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: calling a method  like this `this.getMenuItem` wont work, do this `this.getMenuItem()`

Comment: That was it exactly, case of the missing brackets.

Thanks for the second set of eyes, if you wanted to move that to the answer I can record it as so for you.